# Cannot add records on php sqlite in a Linux server

Tags: php, linux, sqlite, pdo

I tested a simple `Php` program using `Sqlite3` instead of `mySQL` on my own computer and it works fine. What the program does is simple insert of record into a certain table. Now, when I try to do that on a remote web server running on `Linux` (CentOS) with `Sqlite3` enabled it does not work.

I thought at first it was simply a file permission issue since my `Sqlite` file had an initial permissions of **644** so I changed it to **646** then **767** both to no avail.

The `Php` version by the way on web server is a little bit dated, namely, `Php` **5.1.6** but on my local PC it is **5.5.11**.

This is the sample code that I ran on both servers.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:test.db');

$lastname = "Doe";
$firstname = "John";
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (Lastname,Firstname) VALUES (:lastname,:firstname)";

$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':lastname'=>$lastname,
                  ':firstname'=>$firstname));
```

I tried a simple query on a **sqlite3** database on the webserver by the way and it works.

So, could this be a simple `Php` version issue?

I cannot by the way change the `php.ini` so forgo that possible direction for the moment. And I don't have any choice of having a new `Php` version on that server since I use it for free.

Comment: Don't you need to have ";" at the end of your SQL here for it to be executed? http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php

Comment: @Cninroh. Thanks for replying. It has a `;` at the end of the sql statement and it works by the way on my local server on my pc.

Comment: so, line 5 reads like: $sql = "INSERT INTO people (Lastname,Firstname) VALUES (:lastname,:firstname);"; ? because I see only 1 ; in your question.

Comment: @Cninroh If you have a multiple `INSERT` statements then you need the `;` of each statement but this one has only `1`, so no need for that.